# How to monitor GPU Usage in Matlab

Tags: matlab, gpu, gpuarray

I have a question about using the GPU in Matlab. 
I followed a simple code for the code running on GPU on the Matlab website
But when I run the code and I check the CPU and GPU simultaneously, I see that the code runs on CPU instead of GPU!

Actually, Matlab website says `gpuArray()` automatically transfers the code on GPU but it seems the code is run on CPU instead of GPU.

this is the code :

```
r = gpuArray.linspace(0,4,N);
x = rand(1,N,'gpuArray');
numIterations = 10000000;
for n=1:numIterations
    x = r.*x.*(1-x);
end
```

and this is the snapshot taken from processing statistics.

[image]
I would appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Try checking the Performance tab of the task manager instead, and click on the relevant GPU. It will give you more detailed information about the GPU's current activity level.

Comment: What is the output of `gpuDevice` ?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness I tested this command, it detects the GPU and gives me the details about GPU. Also I tested `existsOnGPU(x)` and it gave me `1` which means   `x` is on the GPU. But I can not understand why there is no activity on GPU. 
Could it be related to installing CUDA?